# Which way does the inclusion go?

Tags: general-topology

**Lemma** Let $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B'}$ be bases for topologies $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T'}$, respectively, on $X$. Then the following are equivalent:

1. $\mathcal{T'}$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}$.
2. For each $x\in X$ and each basis element $B\in \mathcal{B}$ containing $x$, there is a basis element $B'\in \mathcal{B'}$ such that $x\in B' \subset B$.

Why don't we write "for each $x\in X$ and each basis element $B\in \mathcal{B}$ containing $x$, there is a basis element $B'\in \mathcal{B'}$ such that $x\in B' \supset B$." (isn't that also true?) instead? I can see that the original statement is true but it seems very counterintuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that we need every $\mathcal{T}$-open set to be $\mathcal{T}'$-open. Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $\mathcal{T}$, then every $\mathcal{T}$-open set is a union of $\mathcal{B}$-elements (and every union of $\mathcal{B}$-elements is $\mathcal{T}$-open), so it suffices that every $\mathcal{B}$-element is $\mathcal{T}'$-open. Since $\mathcal{B}'$ is a basis for $\mathcal{T}'$, then we must show that every $\mathcal{B}$-element is a union of $\mathcal{B}'$-elements, which is what the Lemma shows.

Answer (score 1):

Your alternative statement is in fact false.
Consider any space $X$ of cardinality $>1$ and let $\tau=\{\varnothing,X\}$ be the indiscrete topology and $\tau^\prime=2^X$ be the discrete topology.

$B = \{X\}$ is a basis for $\tau$ and $B^\prime = \{\{x\}|x\in X\}$ is a basis for $\tau^\prime$.

It is easy to check that the statement in the lemma holds, whereas your alternative doesn't.

Comment: In case you intended to use the notation used in the question: You can get the calligraphic $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal T$ using `\mathcal B` and `\mathcal T`, respectively, and more generally you can see the commands for any math formatting on the site by right-clicking on it and selecting "Show Math As:TeX Commands".

Comment: I usually use $\tau$ for topologies rather than T, but thanks for the tip anyway.